# Does the amount of fuel in the tank matter?

Tags: fuel-system, fuel-tank, fuel-pump

As long as there is some fuel in the tank, does the fuel level matter? In other words, is it advisable to make sure the tank is mostly full most of the time, or is this just silly? In other words, are there valid reasons why you should avoid running on an almost empty tank (other than the risk of actually running empty)?

Comment: How old's your car?  Mine's got the fuel pump at the engine, not the tank.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Both previous posts are pretty good.  I'll add a few more considerations though.

- On a low tank, during hard cornering, some cars will uncover the fuel pump pickup and starve for fuel.
- There's been some discussion for years now about keeping 1/4 tank as your minimum as the fuel provides cooling for the fuel pump.  Some people argue that additional cooling will extend the life of the pump.  My take on it is that indeed it does, but that it doesn't matter as the pump won't overheat either way (OEM fuel pump failures are exceedingly rare nowadays, nearly all fuel pump replacements that I've seen done turned out to not solve the problem they were having...).
- Any floating debris will stay safely above the pump intake if the tank level is kept up.  Run it down far enough and that stuff will get sucked in and contribute to either clogging the filter eventually, or even physical damage.

Comment: Debris is a winning point: there will be gunk in the tank and a super low level in the tank increases the probability of injesting that gook significantly.

Comment: Side point on the "keep a minimum of 1/4 tank": it's actually handy for *spouse* cooling as well.  Ever been late to an appointment with your loving significant other and had to explain that you're nearly out of gas...?

Comment: It should be noted that any "floating debris" are not going to be prevented from entering the pump simply because you have some gas in the tank. The first time you turn a corner or hit a bump, the tank will be thoroughly mixed, giving even floating debris a chance at the pump intake.

Comment: @Fake Name, actually you won't be mixed in a single turn.  Mixing will occur all of the time.  The volume in the tank reduces the density of the gunk in terms of stuff per unit fuel volume.  You are correct that there isn't a magic spell, fuel or not, that will prevent all injestion ever.

Answer (score 41):

There is an unexpected effect to running with a full tank *all* of the time: fuel is heavy.  The actual weight per gallon depends on temperature (and thus on density) but it's on the order of six pounds per gallon (or about .7 kg per liter, if you like doing all your math in base 10...).

Obviously, the total weight depends on your vehicle's tank.  In my car, driving full all of the time would be an additional 90 pounds.  That has a measurable effect on mileage, especially in the in-town lowish speed driving that I'm often doing.

I generally fill up, run it down to about 1/4 tank, fill and repeat.  On average, I see better mileage than "full all the time."

As Gabriel notes, however, weather can trump mileage.

Comment: @Drawninpictures - Again, if you'd like to take this up in chat, I'd be more than happy to oblige.

Answer (score 27):

Knowing that gasoline does not freeze (Ok, it will start freezing at -180 degrees, but this is more than you or your car can tolerate) but that a small amount of water can accumulate in yout tank over time.

So, in cold winter weather condition, like here in Canada, if you have a low level in your tank, that accumulated water could freeze and cause some issues, like blocking your fuel pump or hoses.

Comment: You're right: condensation in the tank can be a hassle well before freezing, especially if you're running your tank at a low level all of the time.

Comment: Gasoline actually freezes (or a firm facsimile there of) at around -40 to -50C according to [this source](http://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=2479). Check the follow-up question at the bottom of the page. There are a lot of opinions out there, but believe a physics page might be correct.

Comment: The main components of gasoline are isooctane (melts at −107°C) toluene (melts at −95°C) MTBE (melts at −109°C), xylene (melts at −47.4 °C) and butane (melts at −134°C). So at −180°C it will be already rock-solid.

Answer (score 12):

If you are planning to let your car sit for a while, it also may be adavisable to have a full tank. Less air in the tank means less corrosion of the tank, if you have a metal one.

Comment: But if you are planning to let your car sit for a LONG while, I'd drain the tank completely.

Comment: Most DOT approved tanks are platic.. For many reasons

Comment: Less condensation of water with a full tank also.

Comment: Not all tanks are made out of plastic. For instance Marine tanks are often made out of fiberglass and that fiberglass reacts badly with the ethanol applied to petrol.

Answer (score 7):

I always let my fuel level reach near empty. Other than the cool effect on the pump, I see no advantage of not letting it get below 1/4 tank. Water is heavier than gas, so if there is any water in the tank it will be picked up by the pump first. Same goes for any debris in the tank. The pump is also situated so that on cornering the fuel pump will not be deprived. I will admit that I have run out of gas a number of times, not for a few years now, so feel free to discount my comments.

Comment: In Tank Electric fuel pumps can run hot on low fuel, shortens the life of the pump. I would not run this type of fuel system low on fuel as a habit.

Answer (score 7):

He is correct! The actual pump is inside a canister and unless the tank is bone dry, the pump is ALWAYS submersed in fuel ( even when cornering hard). if this was not the case, the vehicle would stutter and hiccup due to air in the line. Anyone who has ever had this happen, knows it does this only when you completely run out of gas. 
Just look at the design for yourself and use common sense instead of listening to opinion and hearsay.

Answer (score 5):

I also would add that, besides avoiding problems with running always with less than 1/4 (probably, a few times would be alright), you could also avoid being without gas if you are in a jam or need to go to a place which is far than you expect, like giving a ride, and you don't have time to fill the tank or there is no gas station near.

Anyway, I always prefer to be safe than sorry. And I guess there are few reasons, other than monetary, not to keep it with at least 1/4 filled.

Comment: Monetary?  Since the price of gas is constantly increasing, it's better monetarily to fill it up now while it's cheaper.

Comment: @endolith I really see no difference, since really quick you'll have to pay the new price. Unless is up to 10-20% a week. And also, you're contextualizing that question to US residents and also to an specific period of time where the gas is rising a lot, which might me biased and not generic enough to this question.

Comment: The "monetary" issue is an interesting one. Consider that if everyone keeps a full tank rather than a ¼ full tank, the petroleum industry gets four times as much money sooner -- and they don't have to build four times as much storage! So help the oil barons out and fill your tank! :-)

Comment: Nothing like going to a station with your car on "E" and finding that the gas door release has broken and there's no way to get gas in the car.  :-)

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch many cars have an emergency release pull cord in the trunk  somewhere, behind a panel. I suggest everyone should familiarize themselves with its location because the gas doors do fail to open normally from time to time!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter how low your fuel level is, the fuel pump will always be submerged in fuel, the pump actually sits inside a well that is full of fuel, its like this on every car that has an internally mounted pump, otherwise the mass would be exposed to oxygen and a spark can ignite the tank vapors and boom. --- former UTI graduate.

Comment: As Brian's top answer says, it is on cornering that this becomes an issue.

Answer (score 1):

so many things to say on the matter!On newer cars with the fuel pump in the tank the gasoline tends to cool the pump extending its useable life. Next the engine is designed to send an excess amount of fuel forward to the engine and a line returns back to the tank what is not needed. this however allows the fuel to gain heat and this causes the fuel to expand as well as reduce efficiency costing you in fuel milage. Lastly the bottom of the tank can and does accumulate crud over time and the lower the tank the higher the odds are of sucking up larger amounts of it.

Answer (score 0):

Water is heavier than gas and will stay at the bottom of the tank. True, after a little driving the water will mix somewhat with the gas so your going to get a little water sucked up anyway. I like to run as low as I dare so as to get as much water out as posible. A small amount of water running through the engine won't hurt, in fact in some cases a little water is good.(ever hear of water injection) Debrie I don't worry about but I do worry about the extra water produced by the use of ethanol. Best to run this water out a little at a time rather than to let it sit and destroy your tank.

Comment: Wow ... Cannot count on how many levels running your fuel tank empty is bad. There are other ways to get water out of you tank than letting the engine suck it up. If you have that much water in your tank you will stop your engine dead when it sucks it up. If you have an older vehicle and run it dry, you will probably clog the in-tank filter with any sediments. A lot of cars use the gas itself to cool the pump. When you run it dry, you can overheat your pump, shortening the life span of the pump. Just really is a bad idea. Try to keep the tank at least half full to avoid problems.

Comment: If anything, the use of ethanol will prevent the water from accumulating in your tank. Ethanol will mix with water, unlike gas.

Comment: There is also this wonderful substance called dry-gas which is additional ethanol that you can put into your tank it's mostly used in the winter time but you can use it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

yes it does matter

**the common reasons**

- making hard turns can slosh all the fuel to one side in an empty tank and the fuel pickup will not be in fuel causing your car to sputter as if it's out of gas and potentially stall.
- low fuel means certain smog tests can fail
- low fuel means you have a higher risk of sucking up floating debris and clogging a fuel filter.
- in gravity fed systems it could mean you will have low fuel pressure especially if anything is partly clogged.

**the uncommon reasons**

- low fuel is less weight and less weight means faster 0-60 times and better cornering
- low fuel adds to the better cornering because there is less sloshing around potentially causing the car to slide
- low fuel adds to fuel economy due to less weight
- low fuel reduces tire wear due to less weight. in fact you could say it reduces many different types of wear including brakes clutch bearings engine and many others due to less weight.
- consistently low or high fuel leads to more frequent re fuelings which can increase wear on certain parts like your starter
- consistently low or high fuel can lead to having your credit card stolen more often or extra refund fraud from gas stations when they do not automatically refund you the unused fuel.
- low fuel can increase fuel tank damage due to expansion and contraction forces from hot and cold evaporated fuel inside the tank

Comment: If you are doing enought high power cornering to worry about gas tank slosh as a performance issue then you would have already invested in a gas tank with baffles. The last 3 bullets are strictly hyperbole.

Comment: Do you also fill your windshield washer reservoir a pint at a time to make sure your mileage isn’t affected?

Answer (score 0):

We read in the basic schooling and in aviation education, that always keep the tank full to avoid accumulation of fuel fumes specially in hot weathers.
 low fuel can increase fuel tank damage due to expansion and contraction forces from hot and cold evaporated fuel inside the tank.
Weight saving and wear n tear of tires are secondary because safety of life would have more  priority

Answer (score 0):

Moisture can collect on the inside wall of the tank. When temperatures outside hover around the freezing point of water the moisture turns to ice which falls off of the wall and sinks to the bottom of the tank where it can clog the fuel pump or gas line.

In older days this problem needed gas line antifreeze which was added to the fuel. Gas anti freeze is simple alcohol which dissolved the water before it froze. Today, most fuel has alcohol added at the pump, hence no need for antifreeze.